# Convert specflow table todictionary

Tags: c#, linq, specflow

I want to create a dictionary from c# specflow table . I need this as the values in the label and value will change for every feature file.In my current feature file, I have 2 columns.

```
And I submit with following 
| Label         | Value               |
| Namelabel     | texttoenter123      |
| Email         |test@test.com        |
```

Corresponding Step.Tried to use linq.

```
 [When(@"I submit with following ")]

   public void WhenISubmitWithFollowing(Table table)
        {
       //Should be something like this , which convert the table todictionary object
          var x = table.Rows.ToDictionary(k=>k.Keys,k=>k.Values);
        }``
```

Currently I am getting null in this.Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to be flexible with the table column headings:

```
var x = table.Rows.ToDictionary(r => r[0], r => r[1]);
```

Otherwise:

```
var x = table.Rows.ToDictionary(r => r["Label"], r => r["Value"]);
```

Of if you want a quick extension method to TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table:

```
static class SpecFlowExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a two column Gherkin data table to a dictionary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this Table table)
    {
        if (table == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(table));

        if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Gherkin data table has no rows");

        if (table.Rows.First().Count != 2)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($@"Gherkin data table must have exactly 2 columns. Columns found: ""{string.Join(@""", """, table.Rows.First().Keys)}""");

        return table.Rows.ToDictionary(row => row[0], row => row[1]);
    }
}
```

And to use the extension method:

```
var data = table.ToDictionary();
```

Comment: Seems so trivial to implement I'm surprised SpecFlow doesn't already come with this feature. I edited your answer to add an extension method I've been using.

Comment: I did notice a difference between Table objects created in a `When` step versus a `Then` step. When created for a `When` step, the header row appears to be included in the Table.Rows property, whereas tables created for `Then` steps do not. I believe this is so the Table.CompareToInstance<T>(T) and Table.CompareToSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>) methods behave properly. They won't compare the header row. Just bear this in mind for this extension method. The `When` and `Given` steps will have one additional row - the header row. The `Then` steps will now.

Answer (score 0):

Try following if you have only one value per key

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Label", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Namelabel", "texttoenter123" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Email", "test@test.com" });

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Label"), y => y.Field<string>("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Use following if more than one value per key

```
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Label"), y => y.Field<string>("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

Comment: I want to convert the table to generic dictionary , so that I can reuse the dictionary for all values passed from feature file.

Comment: I think you might be confusing different `Table` classes. The OP isn't talking about `System.Data.DataTable` objects. They are talking about `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table` objects (see [Gherkin language documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/#data-tables).